# Given Normal population with mean $\theta$ and variance $1$, find Sample size for UMP for $H_0 : \theta = 0$ against $H_1: \theta = 4$

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing, parameter-estimation

Given Normal population with mean $\theta$ and variance $1$, find Sample size for UMP for $H_0 : \theta = 0$ against $H_1: \theta = 4$ with given probabilities  of type I and Type II errors specified by $ \alpha = 0.05 = \beta$, [Given $P(Z>1.96) = 0.05, Z \sim N(0,1)$]

If I calculate the likelihood function quotient we have:

$\displaystyle \frac{L(\theta =0)}{L(\theta = 4)} =\exp(-\frac{1}{2}\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 - \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-4)^2\bigg) = \exp(-4\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2 - 8n\bigg) $

From here I am not sure what to do exactly,

I saw the Neyman-Pearson lemma which seems useful, seems insofar as if $k$ is a constant and given the critical region $C$

$\exp(-4\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2 - 8n\bigg) \le k$ inside $C$ and $\exp(-4\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2 - 8n\bigg) \ge k$ outside $C$ then $C$ will be the most powerful critical region for testing then solve for $n$
But I still need to use the specified error probabilities.

Insight into this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, you will reject when your sample mean $\bar X_n$ of $n$ observations exceeds $0.$ If you want $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to be equal, then by symmetry the critical value must be $c = 2.$
Then you need to find $n$ so that $\alpha = \beta = 0.025.$

[I think there is a mistake in your question. $P(Z > 1.96) = 0.025,$ not $0.05.$ So I'm just looking at the part of the solution
that is directly relevant to finding $n.$ I'll let you reconcile the result with the likelihood ratio on your own. It's often difficult to figure out what the likelihood ratio result is telling you
without some intuition, which I hope to provide.]

A Type I error occurs if you Reject $H_0$ when it is true.
So you want $P(\bar X_n \ge c) = 0.05.$ That is,

$$P(\bar X_n \ge c) 
= P\left(\frac{\bar X_n - \theta_0}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}
\le \frac{c-\theta_0}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}\right)$$

$$= P\left( \frac{\bar X_n - 0}{1/\sqrt{n}}
\le \frac{2-0}{1/\sqrt{n}} \right)$$

$$= P(Z
\le 2\sqrt{n}) = \alpha = 0.025.$$

So $2\sqrt{n} = 1.96$ and $n = 1$ observation should suffice.

In the figure below the critical value is shown by a vertical dotted line.

[image]

In the figure, the probability $\alpha + 0.025$ of Type I error is represented by the small region under the blue curve that lies to the right of the dotted vertical line.
The probability $\beta$ of Type II error is the small region under the brown curve that lies to the left of the vertical line. (That would be a separate computation similar to the one I have shown you for $\alpha.)$

Comment: Can you give some insight on why the equality of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ forces $c=2$?

Comment: Will try: $\alpha = P(\bar X > c | H_0) = P(\bar X> c | \theta=0) = 0.025$ is mirror image of $\beta = P(\bar X < c | H_a) = P(\bar X< c | \theta=4) = 0.025.$ so $c$ must be halfway between 0 and 4. Think of it in terms of 'symmetry' or in terms of the graph at the end. // After you've seen a few of these you start to understand how $\theta_0, c,$ and $\theta_a,$ must be positioned. // LR test is fine for theoretical abstract justification of that positioning, but many students have to understand that positioning intuitively before making sense of the theory.

Comment: Next, try to understand logic of the Likelihood Ratio in terms of heights of the two density curves. You only have $\alpha$ probability to 'spend' in the critical (rejection) region. Want rejection region to take in as much territory as possible under the alternative density. So you 'spend' it where the null density is high relative to the alt density. Just to the right of $\bar X=2$ on the graph, you see that the blue curve is low just where the brown curve starts to become high. // In last sentence of Ans, suggested you use $\theta_a=4$ to show $P(\bar X\le c)=\dots=\beta=0.025.$ Do that.